# CUDA error: out of memory How to choose the right other cuda resources?

Tags: pytorch, gpu

I want to use a GPU to test a model but I get a `CUDA error: out of memory`.

```
(val_env) jovyan@jupyter-:~/use-cases/Scene_understanding/Code_Woodscape/deeplab_v3+$ python test_shap.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jovyan/use-cases/Scene_understanding/Code_Woodscape/deeplab_v3+/test_shap.py", line 33, in <module>
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 712, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1049, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1019, in persistent_load
    load_tensor(dtype, nbytes, key, _maybe_decode_ascii(location))
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1001, in load_tensor
    wrap_storage=restore_location(storage, location),
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 175, in default_restore_location
    result = fn(storage, location)
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 157, in _cuda_deserialize
    return obj.cuda(device)
  File "/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 78, in _cuda
    return torch._UntypedStorage(self.size(), device=torch.device('cuda')).copy_(self, non_blocking)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

I know that `cuda` 0 is currently in full use, so I have to use cuda: 1 or 2 or 3. How to do it in the code `torch.device("cuda:1" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")`.

```
import shap
import torch
import glob
from deeplab import deeplab_v3plus

PATH = "/home/shared/EC1/Scene_understanding/Dataset_Woodscape/Models/deeplab_v3+/Model_Woodscape.pth"

class Arguments:
    def __init__(self):
        self.device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
        self.seg_file = "/home/shared/EC1/Scene_understanding/Dataset_Woodscape/Models/deeplab_v3+/Model_Woodscape.pth"
        self.img_folder = glob.glob("test_img/*.png")
        self.mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
        self.std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
        self.h, self.w = 483, 640
        self.nclass = 10
        self.cmap = {
            1: [128, 64, 128],  # "road",
            2: [69, 76, 11],    # "lanemarks",
            3: [0, 255, 0],     # "curb",
            4: [220, 20, 60],   # "person",
            5: [255, 0, 0],     # "rider",
            6: [0, 0, 142],     # "vehicles",
            7: [119, 11, 32],   # "bicycle",
            8: [0, 0, 230],     # "motorcycle",
            9: [220, 220, 0],   # "traffic_sign",
            0: [0, 0, 0]        # "void"
        }

args = Arguments()

model = deeplab_v3plus('resnet101', num_classes=args.nclass, output_stride=16, pretrained_backbone=True)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))

explainer = shap.Explainer(model)
shap_values = explainer(X_frame)
```

Here is the GPU I have:

```
(val_env) jovyan@jupyter-:~/use-cases/Scene_understanding/Code_Woodscape/deeplab_v3+$ nvidia-smiMon Sep  5 14:47:40 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100S-PCI...  On   | 00000000:00:06.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   42C    P0    38W / 250W |  32504MiB / 32768MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100S-PCI...  On   | 00000000:00:07.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   43C    P0    39W / 250W |   7811MiB / 32768MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla V100S-PCI...  On   | 00000000:00:08.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   42C    P0    42W / 250W |    926MiB / 32768MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla V100S-PCI...  On   | 00000000:00:0B.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   43C    P0    36W / 250W |   3437MiB / 32768MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I don't understand, seem like you answer it by yourself. Just set `self.device = torch.device("cuda:1" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")` then your GPU index will be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting that argument, i don't see anywhere where you're actually setting the device? You don't actually tell the model where to load. What you should do is change the loaded weight dictionary and also cast the model to that device:

```
model = deeplab_v3plus('resnet101', num_classes=args.nclass, output_stride=16, \
                        pretrained_backbone=True)
model.to(args.device)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH, map_location=args.device))
```